# Inconsistency in string parsing of python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse strings in python. I have posted a couple of questions on stack overflow and I was basically trying to combine the functionality of all the different possible ways of parsing the strings I am working with.

Here's a code snippet that works just fine in isolation to parse the two following string formats.

```
from __future__ import generators
from pprint import pprint
s2="<one><two><three> an.attribute ::"
s1="< one > < two > < three > here's one attribute < six : 10.3 > < seven : 8.5 > <   eight :   90.1 > < nine : 8.7 >"
def parse(s):
    for t in s.split('<'):
        for u in t.strip().split('>',1):
            if u.strip(): yield u.strip()
pprint(list(parse(s1)))
pprint(list(parse(s2)))
```

Here's the output that I get. It's in the format that I need where each attribute is stored in a different index location.

```
['one',
 'two',
 'three',
 "here's one attribute",
 'six : 10.3',
 'seven : 8.5',
 'eight : 90.1',
 'nine : 8.7']
['one', 'two', 'three', 'an.attribute ::']
```

After that was done, I tried to incorporate the same code into a function which can parse four string formats but for some reason it doesn't seem to work here and I cant figure out why.

Here's the incorporated code in its entirety.

```
from __future__ import generators
import re
import string
from pprint import pprint
temp=[]
y=[]
s2="< one > < two > < three > an.attribute ::"
s1="< one > < two > < three > here's an attribute < four : 6.5 > < five : 7.5 > < six : 8.5 > < seven : 9.5 >"
t2="< one > < two > < three > < four : 220.0 > < five : 6.5 > < six : 7.5 > < seven : 8.5 > < eight : 9.5 > < nine : 6 -  7 >"
t3="One : two :  three : four  Value  : five  Value  : six  Value : seven  Value :  eight  Value :"
def parse(s):
    c=s.count('<')
    print c
    if c==9:
        res = re.findall('< (.*?) >', s)
        return res
    elif (c==7|c==3):
        temp=parsing(s)
        pprint(list(temp))
        #pprint(list(parsing(s)))
    else: 
        res=s.split(' : ')
        res = [item.strip() for item in s.split(':')]
        return res
def parsing(s):
    for t in s.split(' < '):
        for u in t.strip().split('>',1):
            if u.strip(): yield u.strip()
    pprint(list((s)))
```

Now when I compile the code and call `parse(s1)` I get the following as the output:

```
7
["< one > < two > < three > here's an attribute < four",
 '6.5 > < five',
 '7.5 > < six',
 '8.5 > < seven',
```

Similarly, on calling `parse(s2)`, I get:

```
3
['< one > < two > < three > an.attribute', '', '']
   '9.5 >']
```

Why is there an inconsistency in spliting the string while it is being parsed? I'm using the same code in both places.

Could someone help me figure out why this is happening? :)

Comment: First thing that strikes me - what version of Python are you using!? `from __future__ import generators` implies *anicent*

Comment: I'm using PyScripter 2.7. What do you suggest that I use instead? :) @JonClements

Comment: You do *not* need to use the `from __future__ import generators` line *at all* then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the binary `|` bitwise or operator where you should be using the `or` boolean operator instead:

```
elif (c==7|c==3):
```

should be

```
elif c==7 or c==3:
```

or perhaps:

```
elif c in (3, 7):
```

which is faster to boot.

Because the `|` operator has a *different* precedence than the `or` operator, the first statement was interpreted as `(c == (7 | c) == 3)` with `7 | c` doing a bitwise logical operation, returning a result which is *never* going to be equal to both `c` and `3`, so that **always** returns `False`:

```
>>> c = 7
>>> (c==7|c==3)
False
>>> c = 3
>>> (c==7|c==3)
False
>>> c==7 or c==3
True
```

Comment: Yes that's what was wrong. Thanks so much, I'm new to Python and I'm still finding my way around it =) @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @Paulie It's also worth noting that `c==7|c==3|c==9|c==2` etc... Can more Pythonically be written as `c in (7, 3, 9, 2)` - which is clearer, and makes adding/removing conditions easier